# LIbrary not loaded - Reason: Incompatible library version

Tags: cocoapods, dyld, cocoalumberjack

I just did pod install of an older project (ObjC based) to latest CocoaLumberjack. In simulator everything works, but on device (running iOS 9.1) I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/69959D96-CAE9-455F-8F74-62A937531E1F/Go 5k.app/Go 5k
  Reason: Incompatible library version: Go 5k requires version 2.0.0 or later, but CocoaLumberjack provides version 1.0.0
```

Any ideas..?
This is my podfile:

```
use_frameworks!

def shared_ios_pods
    # utility
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
    pod 'UICollectionView+NSFetchedResultsController'
    pod 'UITableView+NSFetchedResultsController'
    pod 'PureLayout'
    pod 'UIColor-Utilities'
    pod 'KZPropertyMapper', '~> 2.5'
    # UI stuff
    pod 'M13ProgressSuite'
    pod 'JBChartView'
    pod 'SAMGradientView'
    # Integrations
    pod 'YTVimeoExtractor'
    pod 'Mixpanel'
    pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 3.7'
end


target 'Go 5k' do
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    shared_ios_pods
end

target 'Go5k watchOS2 Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '2.0'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
end
```

This is in Objective-C project and this particular version of CL is I believe Swift based. Not really sure is it relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by the most *unusual* way: full clean build + Xcode restart. Jolly wonderful.